# Exporting and importing states in React

Tags: reactjs

[image]

[image]

Why can't we easily export and import states this way in React? Thus, there would be no need for Context or Redux.

Comment: Please add in the code as code itself instead of image link!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass method higher or dripping down without using redux, content and  other library or hook.

for example

```
Parents
|_Child1
|_Child2
```

Child1 use method to change state i.e

```
export default child1 ({setValue}){
const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

return(
<button onClick={{()=>setValue(true)}}>Like</button>
)}
```

then in parent you declare setValue method, and use it as props in children and child two

```
import Childone from "./Childone";
import Childtwo from "./Childtwo";
export default function parent(){
const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

return(

<Childone setValue={setValue}/>
<Childtwo data={value}/>
)}
```

and then this child two be using the value.For instance can conditional render some staff like

```
export default function Childtwo({value}){
return(

{value && "Thank you for click like"})}
```

But you see, this make many complication when your application grown up. To use information from children, your parents have to inform each other. What if you have granddaughter, or grand-grand daughter etc?

I believed I help.

PS. sometime you can caught an syntax error on children one. Remember to rename or remove the const [value, setValue] from there, and just have it on parent.